# This branch is out-of-date with the base branch in release candidate

Tags: git, github

I have a repo in git with a "master" base branch, where we have been pushing normally.

Now we are doing UAT, so we created a branch "fixes", because we dont want to push directly to master before those fixes have been tested.

So the process is that we continue working on master for other stuff, and when there is something to test we push and merge to "fixes", and then when all good, we create a PR to merge fixes to master.

Now that I try to merge fixes to master, I get This branch is out-of-date with the base branch, since master is the base branch. But we dont want to merge master into "fixes" branch since the UAT still takes a couple of weeks.

What I am thinking about doing is that I fetch master latest locally and merge origin/fixes locally, and check if there are not conflicts, then if not use my admin rights to merge fixes into master.

Is there a better approach?